# Upload file to Linux server to specific location

Tags: c#, linux, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I write small app in C# which should upload txt file to Linux server. It works but not put file in the location I want. Instead of /mvno/myfolder/home/reports all files go to path like this: userdirectory/mvno/myfolder/home/reports - a path relative to user login directory.
In [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx) I saw that for absolute path **%2f** should be used (e.g. "ftp://contoso.com/%2fpath") but it doesn't work here.

```
private void UploadReportFTP(string targetPath, string localPath, string fileName)
{
    try
    {
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(string.Format("ftp://192.168.100.200/{0}/{1}", targetPath, fileName));
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(sFTPUsername, sFTPPassword);

        using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(localPath + fileName))
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
            fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            fs.Close();
            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            requestStream.Flush();
            requestStream.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: [Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @spender I think this question is useful for all readers with this kind of problem. It looks that remarks from [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx) are not correct anymore.

Comment: No. It's useless unless you add the problem code to your question.

Comment: @sallemih there is no path like this is linux `myfolder/home/reports` and actualy this path `userdirectory/myfolder/home/reports` is correct and in fact it is `/home/userdirectory/myfolder/home/reports`. You should change your upload path to someting like this `/home/userdirectory/myfolder/reports`

Comment: @Mr.Sun yes, correct, path is /mvno/myfolder/home/reports. But what I want is to upload file to that directory and not to directory under userdirectory. So issue here is working with absolute and relative paths.